# Using laptop webcam with Android 4.0 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, 3d, webcam, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm working on a head tracking 3D application (take a look [here](http://market.android.com/details?id=hu.molnarm.outsidethebox) if interested). Since I only have a Nexus One which doesn't have a front camera, I can't really test it. Most of the time I'm using my phone and mirroring the image, and I also borrowed a friend's Motorola Xoom for some time but these are a bit uncomfortable solutions.

The emulator supports camera emulation by webcam since r14 but I haven't succeeded in making it work. Most of the time the emulator won't start at all (this might be a performance problem). When it does, the webcam selection dialog pops up and I see my webcam LED flash for a moment (which means it's turned on) but apps using the camera just show the moving cubes (or simply crash...). There was one single occasion when I could see the camera image in the emulator but I couldn't reproduce it.

**Could you please point me to any good step-by-step guides for setting this up?**

**NOTE**: I'm aware that multiple similar questions have been asked in the past but there was no official support for webcam emulation back then so it's a very different situation. I don't want to use third party libraries (or otherwise modify my app) to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the [SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html) to the new r16 version released today and now the camera works for me with all virtual device settings on default values. It's very slow on my laptop but still better than nothing.